# Notepad++ - Removing joined duplicated word

Tags: notepad++

I have problem with duplicated words, they are joined without any space.
For example, if we have literally

```
notepadnotepad
```

how can I change it to single?

```
notepad
```

Comment: How is this happening? Are you asking how can you use find and replace or are you looking for a different type of solution?

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)\1$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  (.+)      : group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
  \1        : backreference to group 1
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1
```

Comment: I don't know where did you get this knowledge and your logical point of view, but it is impressive. Do you have any source so I could learn a bit?

Comment: @Matthew there are several great regex tutorials online; just check a few of them to see which fits best for you.

Comment: @Matthew: You'll find usefull informations [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) and you can download [this book](http://freecomputerbooks.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions.html)

Comment: @Matthew: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use find & replace, for every duplicate.

Ctrl + F (Cmd + F for mac), open second tab (Replace tab). Write, for example, "notepadnotepad" for first text area and "notepad" for second text area. You can mass replace with "Replace All" button.

Also I am nearly sure there is a solution that involves regex to replace duplicates.